# How to solve error in cmake while running my script regarding commad and finding version file

Tags: cmake, cmake-custom-command

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:11 (file):
  file STRINGS file "/home/hasitha/Desktop/ass2/VERSION" cannot be read.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:126 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    build-support/macros-and-definitions.cmake


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:129 (subdirlist):
  Unknown CMake command "subdirlist".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/hasitha/Desktop/ass2/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I am getting this error and I can't find version file in my CMake files. Where can I find it? How to solve all these errors?

I tried to find version file in my CMake files but didn't find it. I need guidance to find that file.

Comment: "Where can I find it? How to solve all these errors?" - We don't know the project which you are trying to build, so we don't know why the project includes `VERSION` file and what kind of content is expected. You are better to ask the project's developer about that..